# Android package name convention

Tags: android, package

According to the Android documentation, the example which is given for an `applicationId` is like this:

`package="com.example.app`

I have created an application which has the following style however:

`myName.appname`

Would this cause an issue with anything apart from it potentially not being unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `applicationId` is independent from the `package` attribute in the `<manifest>`. The *default* value for the `applicationId` is the `package` attribute value, but you can override that in `build.gradle`. The `package` attribute is used for code generation of things like `R` and `BuildConfig`. The `applicationId` is what controls uniqueness. I would recommend that you set the `applicationId` to be something that is less likely to result in an accidental name collision, such as a domain name, even if you continue using your current value for your `package`.

I also worry a bit about mixed case, as there may be things that assume all lowercase characters in the application ID.

On the whole, the application ID does not have to be a domain name. It's just a good idea.

Comment: Hey CW. Thank you for the detailed explanation. If I change the `applicationId` from the `build.gradle`, would I need to change anything else or refactor something? Is the `applicationId` only for the outwardly defining the app, i.e. when it is in the Play Store?

Comment: @Subby: "would I need to change anything else or refactor something?" -- usually, no. "Is the applicationId only for the outwardly defining the app, i.e. when it is in the Play Store?" -- yes, though, really, the primary "outward definition" is on the device. Two apps cannot have the same application ID on the same device at the same time. That's why we can override the `applicationId` in Gradle, so we can have different values for different build types, product flavors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It will not cause any issues. The reason google asks for web address in package name is only for its uniqueness.

Comment: So if this was to be published in to the Play Store, it would be perfectly fine?

Comment: Yes, as long as there is no other app already in the playstore with the exact package name as yours it shouldn't cause any problems.